# Jackson contextual JsonBackReference?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

Let's say I have a parent class like this:

```
public class Parent {
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Child> children;

    private String name;

    ... other Bean stuff ...
}
```

And a child class like this:

```
public class Child {
    @JsonBackReference
    private Parent parent;

    private String name;
    ... other Bean stuff ...
}
```

Now let's say I call the code like this:

```
    // Set up the family with bidirectional links
    Parent zeus = new Parent();
    zeus.setName("Zeus");
    Child athene = new Child();
    athene.setName("Athene");
    athene.setParent(zeus);
    Child perseus = new Child();
    perseus.setName("Perseus");
    perseus.setParent(zeus);
    zeus.getChildren().add(athene);
    zeus.getChildren().add(perseus);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        System.out.println("Serialized Zeus as: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(zeus));
        System.out.println("Serialized Athene as: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(athene));
        System.out.println("Serialized Perseus as: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(perseus));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    }
```

This will output the following:

```
Serialized Zeus as: {"children":[{"name":"Athene"},{"name":"Perseus"}],"name":"Zeus"}
Serialized Athene as: {"name":"Athene"}
Serialized Perseus as: {"name":"Perseus"}
```

This was a bit of a surprise to me. I expected a BackReference to be context-aware and to only fail to print details relating to the parent in instances where the parent was not encapsulating the child. In other words, I expected the first line to appear as I found it, but for lines 2 and 3 to look more like this:

```
Serialized Athene as: {"name":"Athene","parent":{"name":"Zeus","childen":[{"name": "Athene"},{"name":"Perseus"}]}}
Serialized Perseus as: {"name":"Perseus","parent":{"name":"Zeus","childen":[{"name": "Athene"},{"name":"Perseus"}]}}
```

So that the parent propery would only be ignored during json serialization where it is known to be a member of a Child object.

Am I missing something here or is there perhaps another way that I could solve the problem of cyclic dependencies during serialization of an object without severing all knowledge of the parent from the child even when direct access is attempted? (i.e. when mapping this to a web service)?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have a similar problem

Comment: @Aditzu Not quite... I'm not particularly pleased with the solution that I went with but it did solve the problem with cyclic depdencies. I just used
    \@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
(for "children" in this example) which will serialize objects as ID objects. Then in the "Child" class, have an
    \@Id
annotated property. I guess a more accepted-standard way is to use Hateoas for this sort of thing but in my setup that would have pretty much mandated a DTO layer for the web service which I was trying to avoid so I didn't effectively duplicate beans and mappings everywhere.

Comment: 5 years later, we still have this issue. I cannot believe that there isn't a context-aware version of this.